# How do I alter the output of an existing views handler?

Tags: views, users

How do I alter the output of an existing views handler?

I want to alter `views_handler_field_user_picture()` to get the link to the user profile, not the themed picture.

See [alter existing handlers (handler overrides)](http://drupal.org/node/872780). I expect a link like this http://cdn.sstatic.net/drupal/img/logo.png.

```
function mymodule_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['users']['picture']['field']['handler'] = 'my_custom_handler';
}
```

module .info

```
files[] = user_picture_formatter.inc
```

and user_picture_formatter.inc is like this

```
<?php
class my_custom_handler extends views_handler_field_user_picture {
  function render($values) {
    if ($picture_fid = $this->get_value($values)) {
      $picture = file_load($picture_fid);
      $picture_filepath = $picture->uri;
    }
    else {
      $picture_filepath = variable_get('user_picture_default', '');
    }
    return $picture_filepath;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: quick suggestion: you need to override this handler `views_handler_field_user_picture` in order to get user profile image link

Comment: @Aboodred1, is there any hook available ? I dont prefer hacking the core anyway.

Comment: You don't need to hack the core, you need to create a new handler and extend this class `views_handler_field_user_picture` and then call the new handler instead

Comment: @Aboodred1 How to do that?Do you have any tutorials ? or guidelines ?

Comment: I'll try to write the answer for you, give me few minutes.

Comment: @Aboodred1, okay i am waiting. Please help me on this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7552/discussion-between-nikhil-m-and-aboodred1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't alter the output of a views handler. But what you can do is:

- Create your own handler that is a subclass the handler you want to overwrite.
- Add a render method - which will generate the output (this is where your alter code is)
- Use `hook_views_data_alter` to make views use your handler instead where needed.

This will get the wanted effect, where you can alter the output of the original views handler, but in reality to make views use your custom handler.

In code it could look something like this.

```
class my_custom_handler extends views_handler_field_user_picture {
  function render($values) {
    ...
  }
}

function my_module_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data[...]['handler'] = 'my_custom_handler';
}
```

This code is for Drupal 7, but the method can be used in both Drupal 6 and 7. For Drupal 7 you should create the class in it's own file and add the file to the module's .info file, to make Drupal autoload the file with the class when needed.

Comment: See my edit. i cant get it working.

Comment: Hi i've managed to fix it. I accidentally missed an object.