# Ignoring unpublished/published as criteria for "Has new content"

Tags: 7, views

I have rudimentary Recycle Bin system based on Flags and unpublishing / republishing content. However, when republished, "Has new content" displays *Updated*.

I still want *New* and *Updated* for when there are new comments so I'm not sure of the best way to go about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need custom code to achieve this. There's 2 things to know here:

### Updated Status Logic

The [logic](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules%21node%21views_handler_field_history_user_timestamp.inc/function/views_handler_field_history_user_timestamp%3A%3Arender/7.x-3.x) for driving the *New* & *Updated* labels is based on the `history` table (which stores the last time a user viewed a node) & the `node.changed` column:

```
$changed = $this->get_value($values, 'changed');

$last_comment = module_exists('comment') && !empty($this->options['comments']) ? $this->get_value($values, 'last_comment') : 0;

if (!$last_read && $changed > NODE_NEW_LIMIT) {
  $mark = MARK_NEW;
}
elseif ($changed > $last_read && $changed > NODE_NEW_LIMIT) {
  $mark = MARK_UPDATED;
}
elseif ($last_comment > $last_read && $last_comment > NODE_NEW_LIMIT) {
  $mark = MARK_UPDATED;
}
return $this->render_link(theme('mark', array('type' => $mark)), $values);
```

Essentially, it's comparing when a user *last viewed* a node vs. when a node was *last changed*.

What ***isn't known***, is *what was changed* (e.g. the publish status) so to implement some sort of exclusionary logic you're going to have to track the history of publishing/unpublishing to check if the last update was just a change in publish status (`node.status`).

### Updated Status Display

Assuming you have that logic in place, it's possible to [override the output a views field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/62680/45675). Here you can extend the `views_handler_field_history_user_timestamp` class with your own custom class implementing a `render()` method that adds the logic to check whether the last change *was only a publish status change*. In the final step, you can use `hook_views_data_alter` to override the handler for the *Has new content* field.

Comment: Thank you for the info! Not as simple as I'd thought.. It will take me quite a while to 1. work out a good method and 2. implement it. I'll report back in the future.

Comment: Yeah,  a quick lookup to find a contrib module that tracks publishing history yielded nothing for me. I imagine it has to exist for people with complex publishing workflows. Anyway, once you solve #1, the rest should be easy.